# Javascript to group data using forloop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I got the data below

```
const v=[
    ...
    [2,'apple'],
    [3,'apple'],
    [4,'apple'],
    [5,'banana'],
    [6,'banana'],
    [7,'orange'],
    [8,'apple'],
    [9,'orange'],
    [10,'orange'],
    ...
]
```

Now I want to parse it to

```
{start:2 , end:4, value: 'apple'},
{start:5 , end:6, value: 'banana'},
{start:7 , end:7, value: 'orange'},
{start:8 , end:8, value: 'apple'},
{start:9 , end:10, value: 'orange'},
...
```

So I make the loop like this

```
arr = []
v.forEach((j, i) => {
    if (!start && !value) {
        let start = v[i][0]
        let value = v[i][1]
    }
    console.log(start,value)

    if (start && value) {
        if (v[i + 1] && v[i + 1][1] !== value) {
            let end = v[i][0]
            arr.push(
                {
                    start, end, value
                })
            delete start, end, value;
        }
    }
})
```

But I found that each loop the start and end will be reset.
So I need to use another way to loop /parse the data.

Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the same with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to aggregate the fruit elements and the relative numbers,
and then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the result:

```js
const v = [
  [2, 'apple'],
  [3, 'apple'],
  [4, 'apple'],
  [5, 'banana'],
  [6, 'banana'],
  [7, 'orange'],
  [8, 'apple'],
  [9, 'orange'],
  [10, 'orange'],
]

const reduced = v.reduce((ac, [num, fruit]) => ({
  ...ac,
  [fruit]: [...(ac[fruit] || []), Number(num)]
}), {})



const mapped = Object.entries(reduced).map(([fruit, v]) => ({
  value: fruit,
  end: Math.max(...v),
  start: Math.min(...v)
}))

console.log('mapped', mapped)
```

Comment: even i was thinking of same but i have a doubt since in a case start and end is overlapping

Comment: If we write this code in one line removing spaces, it will look like a magic spell: `v.reduce((ac,[num,fruit])=>({...ac,[fruit]:[...(ac[fruit]||[]),Number(num)]}),{})`... Hope, it is not so hard for the topic starter  =D

Comment: @maioman Thanks for your answer, but the 8 is apple and 9,10 are orange again, it should create the new element... Sorry for missing in questions...

Comment: @brk Because the data is for looping in template and I handled if start=end in it

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop checking with the last index that it is the same value.

```js
const v=[
    [2,'apple'],
    [3,'apple'],
    [4,'apple'],
    [5,'banana'],
    [6,'banana'],
    [7,'orange'],
    [8,'apple'],
    [9,'orange'],
    [10,'orange'],
]

const result = []
for (var i=0; i< v.length; i++) {
  var current = result[result.length-1];
  if (!current || current.value !== v[i][1]) {
    result.push({ start: v[i][0], end: v[i][0], value: v[i][1] });
  } else {
    current.end = v[i][0];
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Using reduce

```js
const v=[
    [2,'apple'],
    [3,'apple'],
    [4,'apple'],
    [5,'banana'],
    [6,'banana'],
    [7,'orange'],
    [8,'apple'],
    [9,'orange'],
    [10,'orange'],
]

const result = v.reduce( (result, [index, value]) => {
  const current = result[result.length-1];
  if (!current || current.value !== value) {
    result.push({ start: index, end: index, value });
  } else {
    current.end = index;
  }
  return result;
}, [])

console.log(result);
```